# Simple Inequality Proof Seems Baffling

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

So, a Real Analysis question I've found states:

> For a,b,c $\in\mathbb{R}$, prove: ( $a\leqslant b$ and $c\leqslant 0$) $\implies$ ($ac\leqslant bc$)

But immediately of course this seems opposite to what it should imply, and you can think of any number of counterexamples to disprove it:

Let $a = 3$, $b = 7$, and $c = -1$.

Then, $a\leqslant b$ and $c\leqslant 0$, but $ac = -3$ and $bc =-7$, thus $ac\geqslant bc$.

Have I lost the plot, or has the question been written in error?

Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, should be $ac \geq bc$.

Comment: It's definitely  a typo.

Comment: Ok brill, I appreciate it. Good to know my math's wasn't /that/ rusty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stated property is wrong. It should be
$$(\text{ $a\leqslant b$ and $c\leqslant 0$) $\implies$ ($ac\geqslant bc$)}.$$

Note that $a\leq b$ and $c\leq 0$ imply that $b-a\geq 0$ and $-c\geq 0$. Now recall that the product of two non-negative numbers is non-negative. Hence $(b-a)(-c)\geq 0$, that is $ac\geq bc$.

Comment: Ok brilliant, thanks! Really appreciated.